# Multiplying the decimals in the column

Tags: awk, decimal, multiplication

I want to multiply only the second column by 27.211396132 . I use

```
awk '{$2=$2*27.211396132 ; print }' input file > output file
```

The result is wrong . I want the answer to be like 5 -76308.842049 ( for the first line). Please help me.

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYRxL.jpg)

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZP87.jpg)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html)

```
echo "5 -2804.297202496805723" | awk ' { $2 = $2*27.211396132 ; printf "%s %0.8f\n", $1, $2 } '


5 -76308.84204900
```